# Betfair history API DownloadListOfFiles not working

Tags: python

I was tying to call the downloadlistoffile provided by Betfair History Data API, here is the [link](https://historicdata.betfair.com/#/apidocs). 
But I cannot figure of the issue with my code. How could I fix it?

```
url = 'http://historicdata.betfair.com/api/DownloadListOfFiles'
headers = {'X-Authentication': session_token, 'content-type': 'application/json'}
jsonrpc_req = '{"sport":"Horse Racing","plan":"Basic Plan","fromDay" : 1, "fromMonth": 3,"fromYear" : 2017,"toDay": 31,"toMonth" : 3,"toYear": 2017,"eventId": null, "eventName": null,"marketTypesCollection": [ "WIN", "PLACE" ],"countriesCollection" : [ "GB", "IE" ],"fileTypeCollection" : [ "M"]}'

req = urllib2.Request(url, jsonrpc_req, headers)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
jsonResponse = response.read()
print jsonResponse
```

Comment: You're not specifying `ssoid` in the headers as the documentation instructs. Have you tried that?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I did pass the ssoid as a variable and make sure the ssoid is working fine, so I think it won't be the problem.

Comment: Can you try changing the header name from X-Authentication to ssoid as per the docs?

Comment: You will need to have purchased the Horse Racing Basic package for March 2017, downloadlistoffiles will only work on packages you have purchased